# SQL Server Function That Returns A Delimited String

Tags: sql-server, function

Hey I have a table like this:

```
ID  BitOne  BitTwo  BitThree
--  ------  ------  --------
99  NULL    1       NULL
99  1       NULL    NULL
```

And I need a user function that returns the string "BitTwo, BitOne" for the ID: 99 - which would be the input parameter for the function.

Is that possible?

Comment: In your example, are these really two separate rows in the table? Why wouldn't you have a single row in the table with: 99, 1, 1, NULL?

Comment: Yes its not normalized unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use [SOFDB1]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- exec SELECT dbo.GetString(7)  
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetString 
(   
    @ID BIGINT 
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESULT_STRING nvarchar(max);
    SELECT 
        @RESULT_STRING = CONVERT(nvarchar,(CASE
            WHEN t.BitOne IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar,t.BitOne)
            ELSE 'NULL'
            END) + ',' +
        (CASE
            WHEN t.BitTwo IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar,t.BitTwo)
            ELSE 'NULL'
            END) + ',' +
        (CASE
            WHEN t.BitThree IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar, t.BitThree)
            ELSE 'NULL'
            END)) FROM TestTable1 t WHERE t.ID = @ID

    RETURN @RESULT_STRING
END
```

and call

in sp or something to get the value of that function >>>> SELECT dbo.GetString( theIDtoPass )

Answer (score 2):

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getList (
@id_parameter INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @result = MAX(CASE WHEN t.bitone = 1 THEN 'bitone' ELSE '' END) +','+
                   MAX(CASE WHEN t.bittwo = 1 THEN 'bittwo' ELSE '' END)
    FROM your_table t
   WHERE t.id = @id_parameter
GROUP BY t.id

 RETURN @result

END
GO
```

Use:

```
  SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.bitone = 1 THEN 'bitone' ELSE '' END) +','+
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.bittwo = 1 THEN 'bittwo' ELSE '' END)
    FROM TABLE t
   WHERE t.id = @id_parameter
GROUP BY t.id
```

But it'd help to know how you want to handle when an `id` value doesn't have a value for bitone, bittwo, etc.  If both are NULL or not 1, then you'll still get a comma back as a result.

Comment: And how would I put this in a function, that returns that string?

Answer (score 0):

Well created a table with 4 fields
ID - BigInt

BitOne - BigInt

BitTwo - BigInt

BitThree - BigInt

Sample data

1   1      NULL  1  >>> Output '1,NULL,1'

2   1      NULL  NULL >>> Output '1,NULL,NULL'

3   NULL   1     NULL >>> Output 'NULL,1,NULL'

4   NULL   1     1 >>> Output 'NULL,1,1'

5   1   1  1    >>> Output '1,1,1'

QUERY >>>>>

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(nvarchar,(CASE
        WHEN t.BitOne IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar,t.BitOne)
        ELSE 'NULL'
        END) + ',' +
    (CASE
        WHEN t.BitTwo IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar,t.BitTwo)
        ELSE 'NULL'
        END) + ',' +
    (CASE
        WHEN t.BitThree IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar, t.BitThree)
        ELSE 'NULL'
        END)) AS RESULTSTRING from TestTable1 t WHERE t.ID = @ID
```

You can replace 'NULL' with '' to make empty string there or can put any string

Hope that helps

Regards, J'Sinh

Comment: And how would I put this in a function, that returns that string?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this solution.

DECLARE @Colors VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Colors = ISNULL(@Colors + ', ', '') + cmnColor.Name
FROM  [dbo].[CMN_Sel_Colors] as cmnColor
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Sel_ItemColor] AS itemcolor ON itemcolor.ColorID = cmnColor.ColorID
WHERE itemcolor.ItemID = @ItemID

RETURN @Colors
```